# Intellij showing nonstandard annotations on standard Java classes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

Whilst using Intellij Idea quick documentation feature (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) sometimes I find standard JDK classes to be annotated by nonstandard annotations. Those annotations are not there when one <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-clicks the annotated feature to view its source code. For example, the following picture shows argument of `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList` to be annotated with `@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`:

[image: QuickDoc for java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList]

Why would a standard class be decorated with third party annotation?

This is not consistent, as for example, `checkedNavigableSet` from `java.util.collections` is annotated differently, no package for `@NotNull` is given:

[image: QuickDoc for checkedNavigableSet]

The phenomenon does not preclude development, I am just curious as to the cause of QuickDoc behaving that way. Maybe those annotations put there by Intellij team for convenience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to doc from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html) that annotations are used by Idea's inspection mechanism, so statement `Collections.unmodifiableList(null)` is marked with warning of non-null contract violation. As you noticed this annotations are not  being present in original code, so I guess they were added somewhere in a middle between JDK and Editor. It's still unclear why it  appears with package or without it.